# Selectively display results from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

Simply looking to show a certain cryptoasset's price without the curly braces or "USD", as it currently does, **{"USD":0.4823}** with the following code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XLM&tsyms=USD',
                function (data) {
                    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                });
        });
    </script>
```

and struggle from there forward. Could not make comparable questions' answers click.

Comment: look at what `console.log(data.USD)` shows in browser console

Comment: beat me to the punch charlietfl.

https://jsfiddle.net/m55p7723/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use stringify if you dont want a string representation of the entire object.

Use the objects properties to return their value.

```
document.write(data.USD);
```

Comment: Not a good idea using `document.write` after page load...wipes out whole page

Comment: Perhaps op is planning on writing a bunch of json data in this method and only wishes to write utilizing this method.  This post isn't about the qualms of document.write

Comment: Thank you to both.  What is your preferred method of simply "showing"? New to JS, obviously, beyond copy and pasting in HTML & CSS days.

Comment: Showing? Do you mean displaying text within the page?  I rarely (if ever) use document.write, as pointed out by charlietfl.

It is subjective, but I append a new element and place the contents inside of it, then let my css dictate how that block is going to look and my JS in how the block behaves.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Yes, as in a way to see my code works on the page, in a way that wont wipe out the whole page when I want to take it seriously.  That looks like the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: The other route is static html blocks, grab their id or class, and change their innerhtml.  This is all subjective in whether your page layout is going to change over time (including possibly the containers themselves), which is why it is so highly subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the price `0.4823` of the object `{ "USD":0.4823 }` and the currency "USD" could be "EUR" or others. The below solutions will always show only price and ignore the currency, be it "USD" or "EUR" or etc.

Option 1: Do everything with just Javascript, no JQuery

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XLM&tsyms=USD')
  .then(x => x.json())
  .then(data => {
    const key = Object.keys(data)[0]; // first key, in this case it's USD
    document.write(data[key]);
  
  });
});
```

Option 2: With JQuery, use promise.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XLM&tsyms=USD')
    .done(data => {
      const key = Object.keys(data)[0]; // first key, in this case it's USD
      document.write(data[key]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Recommend Option 1, because it's just Javascript!

Comment: Instead of Object.keys(data)[0]  you can also do Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data)